# How to get mails only after a specific date and time through IMAP php

Tags: php, imap

I am coding for a IMAP mails fetching function. Want to show

```
`$now = time(); // current time

$mailbox = '{192.168.150.11:143/imap/novalidate-cert}'; 
$mbox = imap_open($mailbox, 'username', 'password'); // log in to mail server

if (!$mbox)
echo ('Failed opening mailbox<br>' . print_r(imap_errors(), true)); // remove the  print_r for production use
else
{
$box = imap_check($mbox); // get the inbox

for ($imap_idx = 1; $imap_idx <= $box->Nmsgs; $imap_idx++) // loop through the messages
{
$headers = imap_headerinfo($mbox, $imap_idx); // 
$raw_headers = imap_fetchheader($mbox, $imap_idx); //
$selected_headers = '';
$text_part = '';
$html_part = '';
$original_message = imap_body($mbox, $imap_idx); // save the copy of the entire thing, attachments and all

// build selected headers string
for ($ii = 0; $ii < count($headers->from); $ii++)
  $selected_headers .= 'From: ' . $headers->from[$ii]->mailbox . '@' . $headers->from[$ii]->host . "\n";
for ($ii = 0; $ii < count($headers->to); $ii++)
  $selected_headers .= 'To: ' . $headers->to[$ii]->mailbox . '@' . $headers->to[$ii]->host . "\n";
for ($ii = 0; $ii < count($headers->cc); $ii++)
  $selected_headers .= 'Cc: ' . $headers->cc[$ii]->mailbox . '@' . $headers->cc[$ii]->host . "\n";
for ($ii = 0; $ii < count($headers->bcc); $ii++)
  $selected_headers .= 'Bcc: ' . $headers->bcc[$ii]->mailbox . '@' . $headers->bcc[$ii]->host . "\n";
if (!empty($headers->date))
  $selected_headers .= 'Date: ' . $headers->date . "\n";
if (!empty($headers->subject))
  $selected_headers .= 'Subject: ' . $headers->subject . "\n";
```

Now my question is that I want mails after a certain date and time.How could I do this?

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation of your source code?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a language barrier here so I'm going to try answering twice for you, by making two clear questions and answering them both - which will hopefully cover your problem.

1. "I would like for my PHP script to check for new emails on a fixed date - i.e., on the 5th of July, 2015".

For this, you'll need to use UNIX timestamps. This is a number that has incremented once every second since 1970. That means 1412746422 seconds have passed since 1970 and from that we can infer a date and time. I'll leave you to [read up on how to implement this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) in your PHP script - this is how the date function works.

2. "I would like for my PHP script to check for new emails on a regular basis - i.e., once every hour".

The most practical way to implement this is through using CRON if you're on a *nix server. Search for CRON jobs in Google. Simply, you'll create a PHP script that is run by your server on an interval that you set (such as every hour) - this is not defined in the PHP script but rather on the server. There are plenty of resources on setting up CRON and we have no knowledge of your environment so I won't be providing you with a link.

In future might I suggest taking a moment to provide more information in your answer that you think is relevant. Perhaps if English isn't your first language, try writing out the concept in a couple of different ways - or better yet, provide the reason as to why you need something to work a certain way and we will be able to help based on that.

Comment: thanks. apart from cron jobs my work needs IMAP_Search(). but I want to know how to merge this  function with my current code?